# Using New-Website in a Powershell function

Tags: powershell, iis-8

I have a script that I use on Windows 2008 R2 to create websites with the little idiosyncrasies that we do at my company.  I am having trouble using this script on Windows 2012 and it appears that the IP binding is the problem.  We have always bound our websites to a specific IP instead of using all interfaces.

Anyway, here is a stripped down copy of the function:

```
function New-TestWebSite
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, 
               ValueFromPipeLine=$True,
               HelpMessage="WWW<webidentifier> app pool and website will be created")]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [string] $WebIdentifier,
    [string] $BindIP,
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [int] $Port
)
BEGIN {}
PROCESS 
{
    $name     = "WWW$WebIdentifier"
    $path     = "F:\Websites\$name"

    New-WebAppPool -name $name

    #New-Website -name $name -port $port -ip $BindIP -PhysicalPath $path -ApplicationPool $name
    New-Website -name $name -port $port -ip 172.30.219.249 -PhysicalPath $path -ApplicationPool $name
}
END {}
}
```

The commented New-Website line works fine on Windows 2008 R2 but does not work on Windows 2012.  According to technet and get-help, the ip parameter of new-website is a string, but passing in a string does not seem to work.  The website is created but is unbrowsable (HTTP 400 bad Request - webpage cannot be found).  The uncommented new-website line works, but is bad because it requires that the IP be hard-coded, which I would like to avoid.

Any suggestions for how to deal with this?

Edit 12/18-
I tried the New-WebsiteBinding on a website that I added by passing in the IP previously (as in it didn't function).  These bindings don't work either.  I will try the whole deal on another server when I can.

```
$ip = "172.30.219.149"
New-WebBinding -Name "WWW8183" -IPAddress $ip -Port 8192
```

This is what it looks like in applicationhost.config.  WWW8184 functions and WWW8183 (all bindings) does not:

```
<site name="WWW8183" id="2" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="WWW8183">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="F:\Websites\WWW8183" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="172.30.219.149:8183:" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="172.30.219.149:8192:" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="172.30.219.149:8193:" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="WWW8184" id="3" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="WWW8184">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="F:\Websites\WWW8184" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="172.30.219.249:8184:" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

Not seeing any drops on the firewall.  IUSR has RX on F:\websites which inherits down.

I'm pretty close at this point to punting and putting the sites on all interfaces.  We do use netsh http add iplisten to bind IIS only to the main IP anyway.

```
netsh http show iplisten
IP addresses present in the IP listen list:
-------------------------------------------
    172.30.219.249
```

EDIT - 12/19/2013
tried my function on another 2012 server with the same results.  Binding does not seem to work until I add another one through the GUI and that one instantly functions.

Comment: Does setting the IP address afterwards with [New-WebBinding](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790567.aspx) work?

Comment: I'll try that today.  The thing is that it creates a binding, it just doesn't work.  Adding an additional binding through the GUI does work.  And the site in applicationhost.config doesn't look different

Comment: I tried your script on a fresh 2012 server and it works fine for me. I did lots of Web-Administration scripting on 2012 and never had any problems. Have you tried it on a second server?

Comment: Thanks for trying, that's good to hear.  So far I just tested on my test server, I will try it elsewhere and report back.  note that for your test, you'd have to switch the comments for the new-website line and pass in bindip.